# Is it possible to automate testing involving Two-factor Authentication for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, automation, automated-tests, ui-automation, two-factor-authentication

I have an iOS app that uses 2FA for certain account related features. I'd like to create some UI automation tests for those features, but they require receiving either SMS messages or email. On a simulator, there is no such way to access SMS. I think it might be possible to access the email instead, but that would involve opening up Mobile Safari and logging into an email account- do iOS automation frameworks even support that level of granularity for accessing UIWebViews?.

Is it even possible to have automated tests for 2FA?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to access SMS because you need to know the 2FA code in order to proceed with your automation.  You have several options:

1. Use a fake backend.  After you get to the point where the SMS is sent, supply a known value (hard coded, or otherwise predictable and known by both sides) for the second password.
2. Use a shell script on the host machine to ask your server what the 2FA code was.  This is a security risk, but hopefully you're not doing your testing on a production system.
3. Set your non-production backend server to accept any 2FA code that is given to it.

We use the 1st option.